# Laravel Livewire: Validation in array of object

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-livewire, livewires

I am new in laravel livewire and having a hard time doing a validation array of object.

In the application, there is an item section and the user can add item/s.

[image]

Now all the fields in the item section are required. Once the user submitted form, it did not show the error message in the item section

**View**

```
@foreach($items as $i => $item)
<tr>
    <td>
        <!-- <select class="form-select @error('item_selected_service.{{ $i }}') is-invalid @enderror" type="text" id="service-id" placeholder="Enter member" wire:model.defer="member_id" autofocus> -->
        <select class="form-select @error('selected_service_id') is-invalid @enderror" type="text" name="selected_service_id" id="service-id" placeholder="Select Services" wire:model.defer="selected_service_id" autofocus>
        <option value="">Please Select</option>
        @foreach ($fees as $fee)
            <option value="{{ $fee->id }}">{{ $fee->code }} - {{ $fee->name }}</option>
        @endforeach
        </select>
        @error('selected_service_id') <div class="invalid-feedback">{{ $message }}</div> @enderror
    </td>

</tr>
@endforeach
```

**Controller**

```
    public $members;
    public $fees; 
    public $member_id;
    public $date_delivered;
    public $terms;
    public $date_due;
    public $items                                       = [];
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.fees.billings.billing-create');
    }

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->members                                  = Member::where('company_id', Auth::user()->company_id)->where('status_id',22)->get();
        $this->fees                                     = Fee::where('company_id', Auth::user()->company_id)->where('status_id',20)->get();

        $items                                          = new \stdClass();

        $items->selected_service_id                     = '';
        $items->quantity                                = 0;
        $items->amount                                  = 0;
        array_push($this->items, $items);
    }

    public function store()
    {
        $this->validate([
            'member_id'                                 => 'required',
            'date_delivered'                            => 'required',
            'terms'                                     => 'required|numeric',
            'date_due'                                  => 'required',
            
            'items.selected_service_id'                 => 'required',

        ]);
        
    }
```

Question: How to display error message in array of object?

Comment: try appending the error message one after the other and pass it to the the session so that it can be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

add like this

```
$this->validate([
            'member_id'                                 => 'required',
            'date_delivered'                            => 'required',
            'terms'                                     => 'required|numeric',
            'date_due'                                  => 'required',
            
            'items.selected_service_id'                 => 'required',


            'member_id.required' => 'Member id is required' //Your Error message
]);
```